# Exporting SSRS report to Excel

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs, excel, ssrs-2008-r2

We have a number of SSRS reports and want to show the report in Excel format to the users. SSRS has provided an option to save the report in Excel format (`.xls`), however when the report is saved as Excel, all the cell borders are gone and the spread sheet background color is white. For example:

[image]

Is there any way to prevent it from happening? So the report is shown in Excel with all grids shown as per normal?

Answer (score 1):

There is some Technet information on the intended behaviour of the export: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255234(v=sql.105).aspx

> Images, charts, sparklines, data bars, maps, gauges, indicators, and
>   lines are positioned within one Excel cell but they sit on top of the
>   cell grid. Lines are rendered as cell borders.